# sorting a multidimensional array in php and is it a 3 dimensional array

Tags: php

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ([Dr. Rani shah] => 0.83333333333333) 
    [1] => Array ([Sakhiya clinic] => -0.25) 
    [2] => Array ([Dr. Sharat Gupta] => 1.725) 
)
```

is it a 3 dimensional array or 2 dimensional array? And I want to sort the names according to the values associated with it. I tried all the sort functions available. But it didnt worked for this.

```
$nam[$l]= $name['doctor_name'].": ";
echo $nam[$l];
echo $avg[$l]."<br>";
$d[$l] = array( $name['doctor_name'] => $avg[$l]);
$l++;
```

Comment: what logic you tried for this to sort yet?

Comment: I tried running it inside the for loop and swaping the values if its greater.
Also tried passing the array in asort, ksort, etc functions.

Comment: please write down your code with loop. and write your expected output.

Comment: for ($i=0; $i <sizeof($avg) ; $i++) { 
    if ($avg[$i] > $avg[$i+1]) {
        $swap = $nam[$i];
        $nam[$i]= $nam[$i+1];
        $nam[$i+1] = $swap;
    }
  }

Comment: It's a 2 dimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this -

```
$array = array( 0 => array( 'Dr. Rani shah' => 0.83333333333333 ) ,
    1 => array( 'Sakhiya clinic' => -0.25 ) ,
    2 => array( 'Dr. Sharat Gupta' => 1.725 ) 
);

usort($array, function($a, $b) {

    // extract the keys
    $temp1= array_keys($a);
    $temp2= array_keys($b); 

    // Compare & return
    return ($temp1[0] > $temp2[0]);
});
```

**Output**

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Dr. Rani shah"]=>
    float(0.83333333333333)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Dr. Sharat Gupta"]=>
    float(1.725)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Sakhiya clinic"]=>
    float(-0.25)
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/529936)

Comment: @PragyaGoyal, Glad to help. Please accept the answer if solved the issue.